# Using spring integration web service gateways with JMS

Tags: spring-ws, spring-integration, spring-jms

I need to implement a webservice client (and after that a webservice server) using spring-integration. I have already worked with the samples given by spring-integration team. That implementation uses HTTP as a transport layer. The client is making a HTTP request and server is sending back HTTP response. Instead of using HTTP I would like to use JMS as a transport layer. In this case client sends a SOAP-Request to a Queue (the server is listening to this queue) and while sending it also creates a temporary Queue and set that in the RepyTo in the JMS message header. Server gets receives the request from the Queue process it and then send back a SOAP-Response using the ReplyTo queue. I know we can do it using spring-ws and spring-jms libraries. I would like to do it using spring-integration support for ws and jms:

client sending request: java object -> Soap Message -> JMS message (payload is the SOAP xml) 
server receiving request: JMS message (payload is the SOAP xml) -> Soap Message -> java object
server sending back response: java object -> Soap Message -> JMS message (payload is the SOAP xml)

For example I am giving xml configuration for webservice client that I am trying right now. Can you please check what I am missing?

```
<bean id="jndiEnvironment" class="java.util.Properties">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="java.naming.factory.initial" value="value" />
            <entry key="java.naming.provider.url" value="value" />
            <entry key="java.naming.security.principal" value="value" />
            <entry key="java.naming.security.credentials" value="value" />  
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="/my/jndi/name" />
    <property name="jndiEnvironment" ref="jndiEnvironment" />
</bean> 

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jibx.JibxMarshaller">
    <property name="targetClass" value="zahid.play.si.ws.jms.GetCountryDescriptionRequest" />
</bean>

<bean id="destinationResolver"
    class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
    <property name="jndiEnvironment" ref="jndiEnvironment" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory" />

<bean id="messageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.jms.JmsMessageSender">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="destinationResolver" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageTemplate" class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate"> 
    <property name="defaultChannel" ref="requestChannel" /> 
</bean> 

<int:channel id="requestChannel" />

<ws:outbound-gateway id="wsClientGateway"
    uri="jms:MY.TOPIC?messageType=TEXT_MESSAGE&amp;deliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT"             
    message-factory="messageFactory" marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller"  
    message-sender="messageSender"  
    request-channel="requestChannel" />
```

In the java code I am using: `messagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(MessageBuilder.withPayload(request).build())` to send a request.

But I am getting this error:

```
[jms:MY.TOPIC?messageType=TEXT_MESSAGE&deliveryMode =NON_PERSISTENT] is not a valid HTTP URL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the problem :) Here is the solution:

1) Define a destination provider for your Jms Uri:

```
public class JmsDestinationProvider implements DestinationProvider {    
    private String jmsUri;  
    public URI getDestination() {
        if(StringUtils.hasText(jmsUri)){
            try {
                return new URI(jmsUri);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            }
        }
                return null; 
    }
    public void setJmsUri(String jmsUri) {
        this.jmsUri = jmsUri;
    }
}
```

2) In the spring xml file add a bean for this destination provider and use that bean in ws:outbound-gateway

```
<bean id="jmsDestinationProvider" class="play.zahid.springint.activemq.ws.JmsDestinationProvider">
    <property name="jmsUri" value="jms:test_queue?messageType=TEXT_MESSAGE&amp;deliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT" />
</bean>

<ws:outbound-gateway id="wsClientGateway"
    destination-provider="jmsDestinationProvider"
    message-factory="messageFactory" marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller"  
    message-sender="messageSender"  
    request-channel="requestChannel" />
```